# I try getting members list in a voice channel from a bot and then display on my django app, didnt work

Tags: python, django, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
channel = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(677999369642836037)

async def members_list(request):
    curMembers = []
    for member in channel.members:
        curMembers.append(member)

    return render(request, "discordTool/discordTool.html", {
        'members_list': curMembers,
    })

client.run('my token')
```

I use django and I am well aware of the fact that I need to place the bot code in a different file, my main issue is that I don't know how I would get the members list from the bot if it's placed in a different file? or how to call the bot and run it only whenver I need it to run?

Comment: I'd say either use websockets or a seperate database.

Comment: @LuM How could I use websockets? could you give me an example and post it as an answer?

Comment: That is something far beyond this question. Here is a tutorial: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ , but I won't teach you a whole library in a Stackoverflow question.